# How to add context sensitive help text for custom functions in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, contextmenu

I am programming for using eclipse as an IDE to program in a different language. I have implemented custom content-assist feature using eclipse using the [org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.IContentAssistProcessor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/contentassist/class-use/IContentAssistProcessor.html) package. You can see my output below with the "__XXXXX" functions being displayed as someone types anything based on the context.

How can I display function details of a custom function. I mean, the type of help that can been seen in *normal* functions. I want to give an useful information about these functions.

[image: Context sensitive help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `ICompletionProposal.getAdditionalProposalInfo()` and `ICompletionProposalExtension5.getAdditionalProposalInfo(...)`. Eclipse contains several examples on how to implement these.